# Output directory tree as XML

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, xml, application

HI all,

Is there a linux command which will output the structure of a given directory as XML? if there is, that would be awesome.

Thanks very much

Comment: That sounds like it wouldnt be too tough to implement upstream, you should consider adding an extension to the tree command or ask the maintainer to do it for you: http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/ might not be a solution for right now but it may help someone else down the line. If you don't write it I will, cus its a good idea!

Comment: Hi Andrew,

Yes, this exactly what i've been thinking. I looked at the 'tree' command before I posted the question. I was surprised there was not an option on the command like 

tree /tmp --xml or something similar. Alas, i'm not too familiar with C (i presume it's written in that) so I would struggle to write it but by all means if you can (and of course if you have the time to do so) then that would be AWESOME.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[XMLStarlet](https://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) will do this.

```
xml ls
```

Comment: Installation: `sudo apt install xmlstarlet`, usage: `xmlstarlet ls`

Answer (score 8):

You can do this by using 'tree' command.

```
tree -X <dir>
```

Comment: `tree --help` for all options (HTML output, etc)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no standard linux command to do the job, but google-ing I found that there is a free multi platform: ***[xml-directory-listing](http://linux.downloadatoz.com/xml-directory-listing/)***

Unfortunately it is written in Java.

Comment: Hi Albert,

Thanks. I will give it a go and report my findings :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could easily write a script for that, using languages such as Perl, Python or Ruby should do well.